# How to send the image as file to the server in ionic

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am using ionic and the ngCordova camera plugin to invoke my camera and I am getting my image in base64 formate I dont need to save the image but I need the Image to be sent to serve not as base64. I need to send it as a file formate is there any way to send the image as file to serve my backed is c#.

This is my html looks like

```
<img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}">
        <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
        <button class="button" ng-click="takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
```

My app.js file

```
$scope.takePicture = function(){
      var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 250,
        targetHeight: 250,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
      };

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
        console.log(imageData);
        $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      }, function(err) {
        // error
      });
  };

  }, false);
```

In my imageData i am have the base64 value is there a way to convert $scope.imgURI into file so that i will be able to send my image to serve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`, instead of `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`, for destinationType?

That way, you'd get a file on your device filesystem; then I suppose it should be easy to upload that file to your server...

Then, if you don't need that file on your device anymore, you can remove it.

If you instead prefer handling base64, you could check [angular-base64-upload](https://github.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload) module, which uploads base64 data to a server...

Comment: yes you are right i saw that option but after using this **$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = imageURI;
    },  ** i dont know which one to send the server where is my file in this

Comment: i am new to ionic please help me

Comment: Using `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`, in `imageURI` you get image contents in base64 format. There, you should call the angular-base64-upload module passing the base64 data and your server url.

Comment: I am facing an issue with ios device when i have FILE_URI i am not able to display image but in android works fine